# Validate DateTime before inserting it into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, validation, datetime, varchar

Is there any way to validate `datetime` field before inserting it into appropriate table?

Trying to insert with try/catch block is not a way.

Thanks,

Comment: How are you inserting the data?  ALso, what type of validation are you talking about? Within a certain range or that its a valid format?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Not sure if I'm being overly pedantic there, but DateTime.TryParse will validate whether a value is a valid DateTime object. OP asked about verifying a value before inserting into SQL Server datetime. The range of acceptable values for a SQL Server [datetime](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) is "January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999" That does not hold true for DateTime .NET objects.  This script assigns a value of "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" to badDateTime and it successfully parses.

```
DateTime d = DateTime.MinValue;
string badDateTime = DateTime.MinValue.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(badDateTime);
DateTime.TryParse(badDateTime, out d);
```

However, if you attempted to store that into a datetime field, it would fail with "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

A commenter asked why I used 997 for milliseconds, this is covered under [SQL Server 2008 and milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8153963/181965) but saving you a click, 997 is the largest value you can store in a datetime datatype. 998 will be rounded up to 1 second with 000 milliseconds

```
    /// <summary>
    /// An initial pass at a method to verify whether a value is 
    /// kosher for SQL Server datetime
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="someval">A date string that may parse</param>
    /// <returns>true if the parameter is valid for SQL Sever datetime</returns>
    static bool IsValidSqlDatetime(string someval)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        DateTime testDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime minDateTime = DateTime.MaxValue;
        DateTime maxDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        minDateTime = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1);
        maxDateTime = new DateTime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 997);

        if (DateTime.TryParse(someval, out testDate))
        {
            if (testDate >= minDateTime && testDate <= maxDateTime)
            {
                valid = true;
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

This is probably a better approach as this will attempt to cast the DateTime object into an actual sql datetime data type

---

```
    /// <summary>
    /// An better method to verify whether a value is 
    /// kosher for SQL Server datetime. This uses the native library
    /// for checking range values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="someval">A date string that may parse</param>
    /// <returns>true if the parameter is valid for SQL Sever datetime</returns>
    static bool IsValidSqlDateTimeNative(string someval)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        DateTime testDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime sdt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(someval, out testDate))
        {
            try
            {
                // take advantage of the native conversion
                sdt = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime(testDate);
                valid = true;
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException ex)
            {

                // no need to do anything, this is the expected out of range error
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm looking for a solution to make sure the string I have as DateTime now will be insterted into Datetime field in table without any error.

Comment: Edited to add a simple method that will check the values are in range. Going to try a second approach, might be less error prone

Comment: I'll try your method! Thank you, billinkc!

Comment: Using the SqlDateTime will not work all the time. If a user inputs 10/17 without a year, the method above adds it for validation. But when 10/17 gets to the table in sql server, it throws an error.

Comment: Any particular reason for using 997 milliseconds, rather than 999 when defining maxDateTime?

Comment: Nevermind, I found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153963/sql-server-2008-and-milliseconds

Comment: Good answer.  Would be nice if there was a .Net built-in SqlDateTime.TryParse() so you don't need to catch an Exception.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code above, but I like to looking at it more linear like  if (minDateTime <= testDate && testDate <= maxDateTime)

Answer (score 25):

Try this without hardcoding sql dateTime value:

```
public bool IsValidSqlDateTime(DateTime? dateTime)
{
    if (dateTime == null) return true;
    
    DateTime minValue = (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue;
    DateTime maxValue = (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MaxValue;

    if (minValue > dateTime.Value || maxValue < dateTime.Value)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You could also use the explicit casting operator defined on the SqlDateTime structure; instead of parsing the string representation: `var minValue = (DateTime) System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue;`

Comment: @Styxxy Thank you for the suggestion! Answer is updated now.

Answer (score 2):

This is another take on billinkc's answer. However, in this method the .Value property of the min/max is used to avoid parsing and try/catch. Someone mentioned they wanted to ensure they are inserting a valid date into SQL Server. So, I took the approach of returning a date that is valid for SQL Server. This could easily be changed to a boolean method that checks to see if the dateToVerify is a valid SQL Server date.

```
protected DateTime EnsureValidDatabaseDate(DateTime dateToVerify)
{
    if (dateToVerify < System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.**Value**)
    {
        return System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
    }
    else if (dateToVerify > System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MaxValue.**Value**)
    {
        return System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        return dateToVerify;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" ID="rgvalDate" ControlToValidate="txtDate" Text="[Invalid]" Type="Date" MinimumValue="1/1/1753" MaximumValue="12/31/9999" />
```

OR

custom validator:

```
    protected void cvalDOB_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.IsValid = IsValidSqlDateTime(e.Value);
    }

    public static bool IsValidSqlDateTime(object Date)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Parse(Date.ToString());
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a class with an extension method to allow a check such as `if(myDateTime.IsValidSqlDateTime()) { ... }`:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool IsValidSqlDateTime(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return !(dateTime < (DateTime) SqlDateTime.MinValue ||
                 dateTime > (DateTime) SqlDateTime.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide a bt more information on where the datetime value is coming from; a web form?
You could simply add a CompareValidator as follows

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtDate" 
            Type="Date" 
            ErrorMessage="CompareValidator">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate" Type="Date" ErrorMessage="CompareValidator"></asp:CompareValidator>

Comment: Thanks Naveen, was proving a bit of a headache :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are mentioning about server side validation of your DateTime field, use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx). A quick and dirty example will be

```
DateTime dateValue;
string dateString = "05/01/2009 14:57:32.8";
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue))
{
    // valid date comes here.
    // use dateValue for this
}
else
{
    // valid date comes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.TryParse` is the best validator

```
DateTime temp;
if(DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out temp))
//Works
else
// Doesnt work
```

Comment: not in this case. Every SQLDatetime is a valid .NET datetime but not the other way around.