# DateTime.Now differs a millisecond

Tags: c#, datetime, time

On my application i assign a DateTime.Now to a new DateTime. then i assign it to a value and write it to the database. But then when i get it back from the database and compare the variable to the new datetime assigned earlier it differs with a couple of milliseconds.

Anyone has an idea why this happens?

E.g.

```
DateTime var1 = DateTime.Now;
Object1.DateTime = var1;

Database.SaveObject = var1

Object2 = Database.FindObjectById(objectId);

Assert.AreEqual(var1, Object2.DateTime);
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the column you are persisting this value to?

Comment: Can we have a look at `FindObjectById`?

Comment: is the value correctly saved in Database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 and milliseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153963/sql-server-2008-and-milliseconds)

Comment: If you're using SQL Server and storing in a `datetime` (not `datetime2`), note that the milliseconds portion can only end with 0, 3 or 7 (IIRC)

Comment: @TimSchmelter the find objectbyID is just something i made up to make my point the function in the application gets it out the SQL DB using ADO.NET. Matt DateTime. Dariusz SQL or Oracle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with the precision of DB's `datetime` column: it does not have enough accuracy to store the time up to a millisecond. When you use `datetime`, the time portion is [rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

Switching column's type to [`datetime2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) should help, because its resolution is 100 nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using MS SQL Server, datetimes are only precise to 3 milliseconds so you will find that the figure is rounding to the nearest 3 milliseconds.

See [MSDN - TSQL DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

You may want to use `DateTime2` if you have SQL2008 or later.